# Can't Get All Data From Server Using BufferedReader

Tags: android, bufferedreader

I'm using the below code to read json data from server:

```
URL url = new URL("www.example.com/serverData.php");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8*1024);
String next;
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    total.append(next).append('\n');
}
```

This code is not getting all of the data from the server. When I try the line below to get length of data, it shows around 6000 while server returns more than 10000 characters.

```
Log.d("Stream", String.valueOf(total.length()));
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you talking about bytes or characters? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is since you specified an 8K block size to read, while not adjusting the read loop accordingly with same size chunks.
You can adjust your loop to read and write with regard to expected size:

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(httpConn.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int count;
while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
    bas.write(data, 0, count);
}
origin.close();
bas.close();
Log.d("Stream", bas.toString("UTF-8"));
```

If you don't care for reading chunk size (i.e. you are ok with the platform defaults) then you can try changing your code like this:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
```